# Птичий язык внутри метода если передать в него строку с кириллицей?

Tags: java

В юнит-тестах на java+spring передаю в метод строку с русскими буквами. 
Внутри метода в параметр приходит уже не то, что записал, например статус заказа - Оплачен, а приходит текст на птичьем языке.

```
String response = sendGet(
                new String(serverAddress + "/salesOrder?id=1&status=2. Оплачен");
```

Сам метод

```
 private String sendGet(String url) {
        logger.log(WARN, "prepare sending GET..");
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Type", "application/xml");
        logger.log(WARN, url);

        ResponseEntity responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(
                url, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(headers), String.class);

        return (String) responseEntity.getBody();
    }
```

Соответственно передаю

> 2. Оплачен

, а внутри метода sendGet и на сервер приходит строка что-то вроде

> 2. РІРµСЂР¶РґРµРЅРёРµ

Comment: Какая кодировка использовалась при компиляции?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev хороший вопрос, я не как посмотреть

Comment: Смотря как компилируете.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Компиляция мавеном из терминала. Среда разработки - indelijIdea. Собираю ear -файл и заливаю на сервер с веб-сферой 8.5.5.13

Comment: Попробуйте добавить в pom.xml свойство [project.build.sourceEncoding](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/encoding.html).

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Спасибо, помогло. Оформите как ответ пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы строковые литералы нормально отображались в выводе, нужно указать компилятору кодировку исходного кода. В maven-проекте это можно сделать добавив в pom.xml свойство [project.build.sourceEncoding](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/encoding.html):

```
<project ...>
 ...
 <properties>
   <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
   ...
 </properties>
 ..
</project>
```